# PHP MySQL Select & Update all rows (~10000) every minute

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select three things from each row and then update each row.
The code runs every minute with cronjobs.
However, it takes ages to update all rows in acceptable time frame.
This is how it looks right now:

```
    $update_query = "UPDATE game_1 SET amount=? WHERE name=?";
    $count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM game_1";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($count_query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($count);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    echo $count . "\n";

    $select_query = "SELECT name, speed, amount FROM game_1 LIMIT ?,1";

    echo $select_query . "\n";

    while($count != 0)
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($select_query);
        $counted = $count-1;
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $counted);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($name, $speed, $amount);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($update_query);
        $newamount = $amount+$speed;
        $stmt->bind_param("is", $newamount, $name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        echo "Updated row " . $count . "\n";
        $count--;
    }

    exit;
```

Any idea to have a better performance?

Scriptless

Comment: It looks to me like you are basically doing this `UPDATE game_1 SET amount = amount+speed` only making it a lot more complicated

Comment: And in future, please dont post pictures of code. Post the code as text

Comment: but then every row has amount = amount+speed

Comment: Well eventually thats what your code will do

Comment: for every row he does this: he selects name, speed, amount. then he updates the amount=(amount+speed)

Comment: because every amount is individual

Comment: this is how it looks like: https://i.imgur.com/q4mmGqY.png

Comment: any idea? @RiggsFolly

Comment: `$count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM game_1";` this seems to be the part that's slowing your script down. Select only the required columns with aliases if required.

Comment: another would be `while($count != 0)` - rather than a loop, check to see if the row(s) exist or just a plain `if`.

Comment: the `while($count !=0)` is there to actually create a loop. this while loop is there to select update each row

Comment: it takes more than 5 minutes to loop all rows